# Pure ALOHA protocol: When to retransmit

Tags: protocol-theory

There seem to be two separate cases of when to re-transmit messages in the pure ALOHA.

1. A message is received while a host is trying to transmit a message.
2. After the timer runs down, when a message is sent and no acknowledgement for it has been received yet.

Is it true that according to the pure ALOHA protocol, re-transmissions happen in both these two cases? None of the references I've found make mention of re-transmissions happening in both these cases - it's always just one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ALOHA sender needs to re-transmit if determines that a collision has occurred.  Either of those situations would indicate to the sender that a collision has occurred so the sender will re-transmit.